# Examples of when to use PageAsyncTask (Asynchronous asp.net pages)

Tags: asp.net

From my understanding from reading about ASP.NET asynchronous pages, the method which executes when the asynchronous task begins ALWAYS EXECUTES between the prerender and the pre-render Complete events. So because the page's controls' events run between the page's load and prerender events, is it true that whatever the begin task handler (handler for BeginAsync below) produces, it can't be used in the controls' events? So for example, if the handler gets data from a database, the data can't be used in any of the controls' postback events? Would you bind data to a data control after prerender?

```
PageAsyncTask pat = new PageAsyncTask(BeginAsync, EndAsync, null, null, true);
this.RegisterAsyncTask(pat);
```

Answer (score 7):

Link by Tony_Henrich is very good, and here is another one of equal usefulness: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx

**All** `DataSource` controls are automatically databound **after** `Page_PreRender` (if not already manually before that) - so **yes** you can bind data in all `PageAsyncTask` event handlers, or even in `Page_PreRenderComplete` (which starts only after every `PageAsyncTask` is finished or timeouts).

`PageAsyncTask` **is** best used when working with databases, web services, file I/O and all other operations on which CPU waits for the data to process it - but **not** for CPU intensive or long running calculations (when CPU is busy).

Having said all that, the page will process faster **only** if two or more `PageAsyncTask` are run in parallel - **but**, even with only one `PageAsyncTask`, the request thread is sent back to the pool (limited supply) while an I/O thread handles that operation, thus freeing IIS to receive more incoming requests until the task finishes (then it gets a request thread back from the pool, not necessarily that same one, and continues page processing).

Comment: @Guffa Guffa, your are simply incorrect on **all** accounts, and are just confusing people: the page **does** wait for 'PageAsyncTask's (unless they timeout), and `Page_PreRenderComplete` **is guaranteed** to run only after that. Only new threads and async methods that are **not** registered as 'PageAsyncTask' don't keep the page from completing and returning to the browser. The page is rendered only on `Page_Render`, so you **can reliably** alter any control before the start of that event. For page life-cycle and data-bound controls see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Your link is also dead, takes me to the same place that Tony's does.

Comment: @MadSkunk it's a text called Wicked Code: Scalable Apps with Asynchronous Programming in ASP.NET by Dino Esposito, and you can download the whole MSDN Magazine March 2007
here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A7FA450-1F33-41F7-9E6D-3AA95B5A6AEA/MSDNMagazineMarch2007en-us.chm